# Golang database for storing auth info

Tags: authentication, go, leveldb, database, nosql

I use golang as application server. I do user-auth and I search storing system.

I have next model:

```
{
  email string // it should be index
  passwordhash string // it should be index too
  token string
}
```

I tried to use key-value storage leveldb with 2 databases:

- (key = "email", value = "passwordhash") for login user by passowrd
- (key = "email", value = "token") for storing user's auth info

But I'm not sure that double email is good idea. Could you recommend me solution for storing auth info for golang?

Comment: "passwordhash" should be index too ? I don't see the scenario, that how you serve query by index "passwordhash" with these 2 databases ?

Answer (score 1):

Using email as a unique identifier is fine; you can just append a relevant string to your key to differentiate the key value, such as

- (key = "email", value = "passwordhash") for login user by password
- (key = "email:token", value = "token") for storing user's auth info